# how can i merge 8 images in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to merge 8 images using cvMerge(), but it's not working. What should i do to merge this 8 images?

Below is the code to to see the different bitplanes of an image. And combine all 8 images to be like the inputed image.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include "rgb.h"
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int T(int r)
{
if (r == 0)
return 0;
else
return 255;
}

int main()
{
char infname[256];
cout << "Enter input image : ";
cin >> infname;
IplImage *mono = cvLoadImage(infname, 0);
BwImage pic(mono);
int H = mono->height;
int W = mono->width;
IplImage *out0 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(W,H), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage *out1 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(W,H), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage *out2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(W,H), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage *out3 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(W,H), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage *out4 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(W,H), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage *out5 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(W,H), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage *out6 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(W,H), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage *out7 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(W,H), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage *output1 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(W,H), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
IplImage *output2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(W,H), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
IplImage *output = cvCreateImage(cvSize(W,H), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2);

BwImage bp0(out0);
BwImage bp1(out1);
BwImage bp2(out2);
BwImage bp3(out3);
BwImage bp4(out4);
BwImage bp5(out5);
BwImage bp6(out6);
BwImage bp7(out7);
BwImage b1(output1);
BwImage b2(output2);
BwImage b(output);

for (int y = 0; y < H; y++)
for (int x = 0; x < W; x++){
bp0[y][x] = T(pic[y][x] % 2);
bp1[y][x] = T((pic[y][x] / 2) % 2);
bp2[y][x] = T((pic[y][x] / 4) % 2);
bp3[y][x] = T((pic[y][x] / 8) % 2);
bp4[y][x] = T((pic[y][x] / 16) % 2);
bp5[y][x] = T((pic[y][x] / 32) % 2);
bp6[y][x] = T((pic[y][x] / 64) % 2);
bp7[y][x] = T((pic[y][x] / 128) % 2);
}

// here's the pronlem. i guess

cvMerge(out0,out1,out2,out3,output1);
cvMerge(output1,out4,out5,out6,output2);
cvMerge(output2,out7,NULL,NULL,output);

cvWaitKey(0);
cvSaveImage("b0.png", out0);
cvSaveImage("b1.png", out1);
cvSaveImage("b2.png", out2);
cvSaveImage("b3.png", out3);
cvSaveImage("b4.png", out4);
cvSaveImage("b5.png", out5);
cvSaveImage("b6.png", out6);
cvSaveImage("b7.png", out7);
cvSaveImage("b8.png", output);
cvReleaseImage(&mono);
cvReleaseImage(&out0);
cvReleaseImage(&out1);
cvReleaseImage(&out2);
cvReleaseImage(&out3);
cvReleaseImage(&out4);
cvReleaseImage(&out5);
cvReleaseImage(&out6);
cvReleaseImage(&out7);
cvReleaseImage(&output);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: the `<TAB>` key is usually located in the upper left corner of the keyboard.

Comment: Start by trying to merge 2 images, if you have a problem with that then post a specific question including any errors you get.

Comment: yes, adding 2 - 4 images worked. the first cvMerge worked. but when I added the second and third merge, error came up: Assertion failed. Aborted(core dump)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that unless you have an output image in an RGBA format, the number of channels must be 3, not 2 or 4 as you put it in :

```
IplImage *output2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(W,H), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
IplImage *output = cvCreateImage(cvSize(W,H), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2);
```

Try to set it to 3 and to merge only 3 images at a time.
But I don't think merge can take a 3 channel image as an input... 
Then use `cvtColor(src, src, CV_BGR2GRAY);` before the merge (it will do an average per pixel of the values of the 3 channels).